# Is it possible for google action Dialogflow to open a website in browser?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

So, i am making an Action for Google Assistant in which I want to do this

```
user:- ok google, talk to 'action name'
google :- and google action will open browser and go to the www.example.com to the website.
```

is is possible to do?
if yes, then whats the code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to do what you want. There are, however, a number of things you can look into.

- You can create a [Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) that has a link to your website.
- Or a [link-out suggestion](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip) with the same.
- You can even return a [Browsing Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel) to give users an option of URLs to go to.

But all of them suffer from actually requiring a device that supports a web browser, and not all of them do. Smart Speakers, in particular, don't, but even Smart Displays don't support a browser currently. So you'll also need to

- Make sure the current device they're using [supports a browser](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#response_branching)
- Possibly [redirect](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) them to the Assistant running on a device that does